# How often are the community ads supposed to run?

Tags: support, advertising

I have only the lamest colloquial proof, but I don't think the community ads are coming up. I haven't seen them. When I asked in chat, nobody else had seem them. The stats page doesn't indicate how many impressions the ads have been given, only click-throughs (which is a flat 0 if you disregard me testings the link). Do we know that they're working, or do they come up **that** infrequently?

Comment: We're looking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a sighting in the wild! Hopefully it's not the last.

Comment: Just had a FreeBSD ad sighting - looks to be working now.  Squeaky wheel gets their ad shown, I guess.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I figured that would be the case ;)